# jQuery Autosuggest with mySQL and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, autosuggest

I'm setting up an autosuggest where a person can enter a state and get referred to a page on my website.  I am linking this to a database because once I get this simple example working I will have 50,000 places in a database to look up.  Right now I just have states.

Everything works good except that when a user selects a state from the list, the name filled out in the box is the url link that I am sending them too rather than the correct label.  (But I am still going to send them to a url.)  Its a small point but it just doesn't look right.  Any ideas?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#searchbox').autocomplete({
        source:'suggest.php', 
        minLength:1,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $( "#searchbox" ).val( ui.item.label );
            var url = ui.item.value;
            if(url != '#') {
                window.location.href = url;
            }
        },
        html: true,
        open: function(event, ui) {
            $(".ui-autocomplete").css("z-index", 1000);
        }                   
    });
});
```

The php returns both the web link and the label being searched:

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC) )
{
    $data[] = array(
        'label' => $row['Label'],
        'value' => $row['Link']
    );
}
```

Here is the example running [1](http://www.towncharts.com/newtest.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `select` method's default behaviour is to set the textbox to use `value` instead of `label`. So using `$( "#searchbox" ).val( ui.item.label );` won't work, regardless of the string you put in there. In that case, we should stop the default behaviour.

Putting `event.preventDefault()` in the select function seems to fix the problem.

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $( "#searchbox" ).val( ui.item.label );
    var url = ui.item.value;
    if(url != '#') {
        window.location.href = url;
        }
    }
```